# Peak detection techniques

Tags: signal-analysis, signal-detection, peak-detection

I'm using a cell-averaging constant false-alarm rate (CA-CFAR) detector to detect peaks like the first one in the following plot:

[image]

The magenta line is the adaptive threshold, which is the local standard deviation multiplied by a contrast factor. What other peak-detection techniques could I try in this context?

Comment: Well, what have you tried and what doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, generally "fishing" questions like this tend to be closed as too broad.  Can you give a little more information about what you'd prefer to happen?  If there's a specific issue you're trying to get around, that may help us to help you.  CA-CFAR seems like a good approach, without any other considerations to take account of.

Comment: I have tried using a constant threshold and an adaptive one (CFAR). Constant thresholds don't work very well under unknown (and varying) interference levels, which is why I looked into CFAR. I was wondering whether I am missing any other standard detection technique.

Comment: It would be lot more effective and likely to be answered if a more detailed, mathematical, description were generated.  For instance: what is a "peak"?  Is it the true absolute peak in a group of numbers?  Or a data point that is surrounded by 5 (?) lower points on each side.  Typically a mathematical statement of the problem is necessary before an analysis can be done.  Are there outliers to be tossed?  Is this a signal+noise?  What generates the noise?     Do the "peaks" correspond to fractures in a window or variances of manufacturing machinery?